# How to get data path from firestore firebase using Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I created a note application, in the application I send some information to firestore using this 
**send method**

```
val notesToSend = NotesModel(
                noteTitle,
                noteText,
                Calendar.getInstance().time,
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid,
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid,
                currentUser.name
            )

            FirestoreUtil.sendNotes(notesToSend, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
```

**sendNotes**

```
private val notesChannnelsCollectionRef = firestoreInstance.collection("notesChannels")

    fun sendNotes(notes: Notes,userId: String){
        notesChannnelsCollectionRef.document(userId)
            .collection("notes")
            .add(notes)
    }
```

How to get data path from database?

**photo of database**
[image] 
[image]

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?

Comment: i read this article. I dont understand how to get document return path in code how this realise

Comment: In that case I'd recommend also taking the [Firestore codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/index.html). It's unlikely that we'll do a better job explaining it here than the documentation does.

Comment: Have you solved the issue of getting data from Firestore? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

As Puff pointed on [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#kotlin+ktx_1) it mentions how to get the document using the Doc Reference. [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/631484a1407da3dde3cfce23324a466ffd3f01b3/firebase-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.java#L59) is the Firebase SDK where analizing the `DocumentReference` class you can get the path from the Reference with function `getPath()`

So the code to get the path would be:

```
val docRef = db.collection(COLLECTION_ID).document(DOCUMENT_ID)
val docPath = docRef.getPath()
```